# French porn urls logging 404 errors to non-porn site

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I've noticed a string of 404 status codes being logged in a client's error log for non-existent urls. The site is a .NET MVC site and the exact error being logged is "The controller path for '/video/######/french-name-of-looks-like-porn.html' was not found or does not implement IController." The first errors occurred at the beginning of February of this year and continue through today - 175 in February, 246 in March, 790 in April, and 144 so far in May.

All of the requests are coming from a small block of IPs in China - 180.76.5.10 to 180.76.6.37.

Besides the use of resources, should I be worried about this?

Comment: Counterfeit porn? A chinese company has taken the genuine (french) thing and simply rebadged it but done an incomplete job?

Comment: I figure it's something along those lines, but why would my client's site be getting hit?

Comment: Possibly a mis-spelling in the domain name or routing rule causing requests to come to your site rather than theirs?

Comment: Maybe your clients domain name used to belong to a porn site.

Comment: The client has had this domain for several years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple possibilities here; but I'll keep to the most likely one:

It's likely that some site has incorrectly set the link for a video page to your client's DNS name.  A bunch of that crap is hosted on cracked domains and your client's DNS name may be *close* to a name of a site that was cracked and they are the victim of a typo.  Not much you can do about this.  At some point someone on their side *may* notice and fix it.  Or they might not and you'll see this for quite some time.

Comment: Thanks. @slugster suggested something similar; I just wanted to be sure that this wasn't malicious in any way.

Comment: @virtuesplea: Oh, it very well might be malicious... just that your client's site isn't impacted by it.

Comment: @virtuesplea Currently the misdirected request is probably causing a small inline error on the containing page - can you return something that will either cause the page to blow up or redirect the whole page to a URL you nominate? That would annoy anyone trying to watch the video and make it more likely that they report the problem (if it is legit). If it isn't legit then just consider it payback.

Comment: @slugster: or better yet... have the URL respond with a single frame video stating something along the lines of "Your IP address has been logged and forwarded to your local authorities.  Viewing this content is illegal."  hehe.

Comment: @ChrisLively, that would be lovely. I don't know that my boss or the client would let me though

Comment: @virtuesplea: In that case I would either leave things alone, or, if seeing that message in the logs is upsetting people then simply filter out that particular error message and not even bother logging it.